# New Windows 10 Laptop - Unable to install SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, windows

I'm getting the exact same error message as see in this blog post:
http://shawndowler.com/blog/2012/06/25/microsoft-sql-server-installation-issue-fix/

I ran the SQL Server 2012 setup exe (renamed it to setup.exe it was the expresss edition) as Admin from the command prompt specifying to install the updates prior which exists in my 'C:\Updates' and got the exact same error message as the blogger "An error occurred during the installation of an assembly"

Someone commented it resolved their issue for SQL 2012 in Windows 10 (I'm using express, they didnt specify which version).

Anyone else had issues with SQL 2012 or other installing on Windows 10 complaining about Microsoft.VC80.MCF or similar?

Comment: Did you check to see if there's a `setup.exe` in `C:\Updates`?

Comment: It doesn't exist, when i change it to run the sql file set-up which does exists it states: C:\Updates>SQLServer2012-KB2703275-x64.exe /Action=Install /UpdateEnabled=True /UpdateSource="C:\Updates"
Access is denied.

Comment: You need to be running in an Administrator command window. (This is basic computer use; you can't run an executable that doesn't exist, and you can't install software without running as an admin.)

Comment: I ran the SQL Server 2012 setup exe (renamed it to setup.exe) as Admin from the command prompt specifying to install the updates prior which exists in my 'C:\Updates' and got the exact same error message as the blogger "An error occurred during the installation of an assembly"

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, you need at least SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 2 - RTM version isn't supported. For some reason, it is only mentioned in documentation regarding SQL Server 2014: [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx#Anchor_2).

Hopefully, with Express edition you can download the correct version with SP [already integrated into it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351). However, it might be wiser to install SP3 instead and save yourself some hassle in the future.